# Best tutorial for developing Daaps that work with Metamask?

Tags: web3js, dapp-development

I have my smart contract deployed and all I need to do now is build a convenient UI that works with Chrome and Metamask. My benchmark Dapp is [Etherdeta](https://etherdelta.github.io/) which was build using nothing but jquery. What is a good tutorial that walks me through the basics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a good tutorial to learn the basics.
[Full Stack Hello World Voting Ethereum Dapp](https://medium.com/@mvmurthy/full-stack-hello-world-voting-ethereum-dapp-tutorial-part-1-40d2d0d807c2)

Answer (score 2):

I propose you to follow this good entry point : https://gist.github.com/flyswatter/aea93752fb90322bbe11

Comment: link is dead, please update it.